# How can i update nested data by using mongoose findByIdAndUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

i can not able to update nested data in my mongodb. here is my "update" module at back-end side.

```
exports.updateOne = (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body) {
    return res.status(400).send({
      message: "Data to update can not be empty!"
    });
  }
  const {id} = req.params;
  console.log(req.body);
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body, { useFindAndModify: false, new: true}).populate('basic')
    .then(data => {
      if (!data) {
        res.status(404).send({
          message: `Cannot update User with id=${id}. Maybe User was not found!`
        });
      } else 
      res.send({ message: "User was dupdated successfully." , data});
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
        err.message || "Error updating User with id=" + id
      });
    });
};
```

and my front-end side is;

```
onChangePosition(e) {
    const position = e.target.value;
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      currentStaff: {
        ...prevState.currentStaff,
        basic:
        {
          ...prevState.currentStaff.basic,
          position:position
        }
        }
    }));
  }
  onChangeEmail(e) {
    const emailBusiness = e.target.value;
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      currentStaff: {
        ...prevState.currentStaff,
        emailBusiness:emailBusiness
        }
    }));
  }
  updateStaff() {
    StaffDataService.updateOne(
      this.state.currentStaff.id,
      this.state.currentStaff
    ).then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    })
  }
```

i can change state properly, and my sending data "req.body" is what i want (it is an object). There is no problem.
as you see above, i can update "email" because it is on the main body of object, but can not update "position" (nested element) because it is inside of basic (populated data).
i tried different methods by mongoose, and tried "$set" command.
Can anyone solve this?

Comment: You, my friend, making a big mistake allowing naked `req.body` to be written in your collection via `User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body` . First, it's unsecured.The second thing is: what is it? javascript object? Maybe a json? And what if it's `null` or `undefined` ?

Comment: i understand your mention for req.body, but im trying to make alerts if it is `null` or `undefined`. The point is there is many fields, admin can update; because of this i am sending whole `req.body`. i will inspect this security problems later, Thanks. What abut my main problem; populated data update?

Answer (score 0):

To update, the nested value/object in your document, you should use dot notations, so it depends from the `req.body` variable value.

1. `req.body` shouldn't be a Mongoose doc. In such case you `mongoose.toObject`.
2. Second thing is:

   [update] Object should be: `field_with_subdocument.key_value: updated_propery`

like this:

```js
/** Example doc */
{
  _id: 1,
  parent_field: {
     baby_field: value
  }
}
/** Inside async function */
...await Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { "parent_field.baby_field": value })

Also, take a look at [`{overwrite: true}`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) option. It might be useful to you.
```

Comment: for your example, if i got many `baby_fields` to update, i need to write several methods for each element. Can i update all fields by one line. i mean whole `parent_field` object? May be not update but replace.

Comment: @MustafaT Can i update all fields by one line? - Yes, you can!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, In my case, the defined mongoose schema for that model did not match the nested Object I was passing to the `findByIdAndUpdate` method. let me simplify it, here is the model

```
import { model, Schema } from 'mongooose';
const UserModel = model('user', new Schema({
  profile: {
    avatar: String,
    bio: String,
  }
}));
```

And here is the update query:

```
async function getDefaultProfile() {
  const user = await UserModel.findById(process.env.DEFAULT_USER);
  return user.profile;
}

const profile = await getDefaultProfile();
UserModel.findByIdAndUpdate('user id', { 
  $set: { 
    profile: profile
  } 
});
```

The important note was that my `getDefaultProfile` function returns a mongoose nested object, not a pure object. So in the returned object, I had $set, $get, etc function. So as you know this object is not what we define in the mongoose model, therefore the mongoose ignores it.

So I guess you have the same problem, or something close to my issue.

**What should I do?**

1. Run your project in debugging mode.
2. then check `req.body` or whatever that gives you the nested object (in my case `getDefaultProfile`).
3. Check it with your model, Are they equal?

---

And if that solution does not work for you, please try this solution, write a utility function:

```
export async function flatObjectAndSeparateThemByDot(
    object: any,
): Promise<any> {
    const res: any = {};
    (function recurse(obj: any, current?: string) {
        for (const key in obj) {
            const value = obj[key];
            // joined keys with dot
            const newKey = current ? current + '.' + key : key;
            if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
                // it's a nested object, so do it again
                recurse(value, newKey);
            } else {
                // it's not an object, so set the property
                res[newKey] = value;
            }
        }
    })(object);

    return res;
}
```

then you can pass your nested object to this function and you will get something like this: `{ "profile.avatar": "lorem ipsum", "profile.bio": "bio temp" }`. So to show you how this function works I will write a sample code:

```
const sampleProfile = {
  profile: {
    avatar: "asd",
    bio: "sample"
  }
}
const profile = await flatObjectAndSeparateThemByDot(sampleProfile);
await UserModel.findByIdAndUpdate('user id', {
  $set: {
    // other fields,
    ...profile
  }
});
```